# Spring boot 3 waiting in Initializing JpaMetamodelMappingContext

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

After migrate my project to spring boot 3 my application dose not start and wait in this line

```
return factories.stream() //
                .map(EntityManagerFactory::getMetamodel) //
                .collect(StreamUtils.toUnmodifiableSet());
```

this log is in this class JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java
I dont know how resolve this problem

```
/*
 * Copyright 2017-2023 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import jakarta.persistence.metamodel.Metamodel;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.util.StreamUtils;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;

/**
 * {@link FactoryBean} to setup {@link JpaMetamodelMappingContext} instances from Spring configuration.
 *
 * @author Oliver Gierke
 * @author Mark Paluch
 * @since 1.6
 */
public class JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean<JpaMetamodelMappingContext>
        implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.class);

    private @Nullable ListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return JpaMetamodelMappingContext.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected JpaMetamodelMappingContext createInstance() {

        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("Initializing JpaMetamodelMappingContext…");
        }

        JpaMetamodelMappingContext context = new JpaMetamodelMappingContext(getMetamodels());
        context.initialize();

        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("Finished initializing JpaMetamodelMappingContext");
        }

        return context;
    }

    /**
     * Obtains all {@link Metamodel} instances of the current {@link ApplicationContext}.
     *
     * @return
     */
    private Set<Metamodel> getMetamodels() {

        if (beanFactory == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("BeanFactory must not be null");
        }

        Collection<EntityManagerFactory> factories = BeanFactoryUtils
                .beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(beanFactory, EntityManagerFactory.class).values();

        return factories.stream() //
                .map(EntityManagerFactory::getMetamodel) //
                .collect(StreamUtils.toUnmodifiableSet());
    }
}
```

Terminal log

```
2023-03-01T11:23:45.856+03:30 DEBUG 278870 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jpaAuditingHandler'
2023-03-01T11:23:45.856+03:30 DEBUG 278870 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jpaMappingContext'
2023-03-01T11:23:49.292+03:30 DEBUG 278870 --- [           main] .c.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean : Initializing JpaMetamodelMappingContext…
```

pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.3


jar

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</mapstruct.version>
    <spring-cloud-dependencies.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud-dependencies.version>
    <jjwt.version>0.11.5</jjwt.version>
    <hibernate.version>6.1.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate-envers.version>${hibernate.version}</hibernate-envers.version>
    <springdoc-openapi>2.0.2</springdoc-openapi>
    <ds-proxy-spring-boot-starter.version>1.7.1</ds-proxy-spring-boot-starter.version>
    <blaze-persistence.version>1.6.4</blaze-persistence.version>
    <lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>0.2.0</lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>
    <oracle.driver.version>19.15.0.0.1</oracle.driver.version>
    <oracle.ndriver.version>19.3.0.0</oracle.ndriver.version>
    <kipit-captcha.version>4.0.0</kipit-captcha.version>
    <kipit-thirdparty.version>0.0.1</kipit-thirdparty.version>
    <persian-date-time.version>4.2.1</persian-date-time.version>
    <logstash-logback-encoder.version>7.3</logstash-logback-encoder.version>
    <logbook.version>2.15.0</logbook.version>
    <jib-maven-plugin.version>3.3.1</jib-maven-plugin.version>
    <jib-maven-plugin.image>openjdk:17-oracle</jib-maven-plugin.image>
    <jib-maven-plugin.architecture>amd64</jib-maven-plugin.architecture>
    <java-jwt.version>4.3.0</java-jwt.version>
    <otp-java.version>1.3.2</otp-java.version>
    <spring-boot.version>3.0.3</spring-boot.version>
    <spring-cloud-starter-sleuth.version>3.1.7</spring-cloud-starter-sleuth.version>
    <spring-cloud-stream.version>4.0.1</spring-cloud-stream.version>
    <hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60.version>3.2.0</hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60.version>
    <jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations.version>2.14.2</jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations.version>
    <hibernate-jcache.version>${hibernate.version}</hibernate-jcache.version>
    <ehcache.version>3.10.8</ehcache.version>
    <cache-api.version>1.1.1</cache-api.version>
    <mockserver-client-java-no-dependencies.version>5.14.0</mockserver-client-java-no-dependencies.version>
    <commons-text.version>1.10.0</commons-text.version>
    <commons-codec.version>1.15</commons-codec.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-dependencies.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>${oracle.driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
         <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
         <version>${oracle.ndriver.version}</version>
     </dependency


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-envers.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60</artifactId>
        <version>${hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springdoc-openapi}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>${logstash-logback-encoder.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
        <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${logbook.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>${java-jwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.bastiaanjansen</groupId>
        <artifactId>otp-java</artifactId>
        <version>${otp-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mfathi91</groupId>
        <artifactId>persian-date-time</artifactId>
        <version>${persian-date-time.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockserver-client-java-no-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${mockserver-client-java-no-dependencies.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-text.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>app</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    
</build>
```

Comment: You can try to set the `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization` property to `true` in your `application.yml` file to defer the initialization of the JPA metamodel until the first entity manager is created. This may help to avoid any issues with the initialization process

Comment: I had set this spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=deferred but didn't work

Comment: Is there an easy way to replicate this? Or a thread dump of this state? If so, please file a ticket? Do you register any kind of Hibernate extensions that, directly or indirectly depend on some Spring Data infrastructure? This might cause a cyclic dependency that could result in a deadlock.

Comment: @OliverDrotbohm After change  bootstrap-mode from deferred to   default application start successful